# mapping between routes and direction using javascript or python graph or tree?

Tags: javascript, python, data-structures, graph

I need to create the relationship between routes and direction. I am not sure which data structure is appropriate for me and how should I proceed. Currently I have two lists/arrays. One array contains routes and another contains direction. For example, routes = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] directions = ["north","south","west","east","inbound","outbound"]. Some of these routes(as in bus service) goes only in 2 directions, 1 direction,etc . For example say 11,12,19 goes north and south. 18,20 goes to to inbound and outbound. 17 goes only inbound. 14,15 goes to all the directions.

So what would be better approach to implement this in JavaScript or python. I can see this as a graph DS problem. Can anyone help me or know better approach

Comment: if the routes don't need to correlate to each other, something as simple as a `dict` in python. would look something like `{11 : ['north', 'south'], 17 : ['inbound'], ...}` OR the reciprocal of {'north' : [11, 12, 14, 15, 19], 'inbound' : [17,18,...],...}` depending on how you want the data to be accesible

Comment: didn't thought of dict approach. But I think it would solve the problem but on the larger scale this approach might be slow right?

Comment: getting values from a dict is theoretically `O(1)` because its just a hashmap. Depends on what you define as slow.

Comment: oh I see... If you could post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could structure your data like a `dict` in Python (which is essentially a hashmap). The idea is that you have key : value pairs that are easily accessible.

Depending on how you need to access the data, you could structure it like this:

```
{
     11 : ['north', 'south'],
     17 : ['inbound'],
     ...
}
```

Where the key are the routes and the values are the list of directions.

OR

You could structure like this:

```
{
    'north' : [11, 12, 14, 15, 19],
    'inbound' : [17, 18, ...],
    ...
}
```

Where the keys are the directions and the values are the list of routes that go in that direction.

Getting values in a dict is O(1) and looking up values in a list is O(n). To get even better speeds, you could instead use a `set` for the values, which has a lookup speed of O(1) as well.